# Erro ao executar npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

Recém instalei o linux deepin em meu pc, instalei o node.js 10.0.6 juntamente com o npm 6.0.4. Ao rodar o `npm install` , ele da erro, então executei o seguinte comando: `npm audit fix --force` e obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /home/user/Documents/helloWorld/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

sh: 1: node: Permission denied

> node-sass@4.9.0 install /home/user/Documents/helloWorld/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied

> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /home/user/Documents/helloWorld/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
added 200 packages from 137 contributors in 4.998s
fixed 0 of 0 vulnerabilities in 3520 scanned packages
```

Como posso solucionar este defeito ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar rodar o comando após atribuir as devidas permissões:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

E então, rodar o seu comando:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Fonte: [Github issue](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1407)